# planning_environment in electric for clearing known objects

Tags: ros, planning-environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

planning_environment has been changed in electric as compared to diamondback. Can anyone please point out what is corresponding to these lines in electric (node for clearing known objects?).

Thanks!

```
<!--clearing known objects from the laser data-->
<node pkg="planning_environment" type="clear_known_objects" name="laser_clear_objects" output="screen">
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="tilt_scan_cloud" />
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="tilt_scan_cloud_known" />
    <param name="sensor_frame" type="string" value="base_scan_link" />              

    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
    <param name="object_padd" type="double" value="0.02" />
    <param name="object_scale" type="double" value="1.0" />
</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11648/planning_environment-in-electric-for-clearing-known-objects/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2011-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good introduction to the new arm navigation stacks in Electric is in a recent IROS tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/IROS2011). Working through that tutorial may answer a lot of your questions.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0